# How do i plot a single figure but with two boxplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

As my question says, I want to know how to plot two boxplots in a single figure. That's my actual code:

```
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
bplot2 = plt.boxplot(dff['totlngth'], vert = 1, patch_artist = True)
for box in bplot2['boxes']:
  box.set(facecolor = 'pink')
for median in bplot2['medians']:
  median.set_color('black')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
bplotm2 = plt.boxplot(dfm['totlngth'], vert = None, patch_artist = True)
for box in bplotm2['boxes']:
  box.set(facecolor = 'Lightblue')
for median in bplotm2['medians']:
  median.set_color('black')
plt.yticks([75, 80, 85, 90, 95])
```

I'm pretty beginner at python for data analysis and I just want to know if there's a easy way to do it, since I'm still learning slowly.

I know that subplots plots figures apart, but I tried without it and got a single figure with both plots one upon the other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want -- when I make a MVCE from your code I get two boxplots in a single figure; maybe you also wanted them in a single axes? (Matplotlib uses those terms very specifically: plots live in axes which live in figures).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's easier if you switch to specifying your figures and axes. Here's a minimal alteration to the [gallery example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/stats/boxplot_plot.html#sphx-glr-plot-types-stats-boxplot-plot-py):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('_mpl-gallery')

# make data:
np.random.seed(10)
D = np.random.normal((3, 5, 4), (1.25, 1.00, 1.25), (100, 3))
E = np.random.normal((2, 1, 5), (1.33, 1.00, 1.50), (100, 3))

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
BpD = ax.boxplot(D, positions=[2, 4, 6], widths=1.5, patch_artist=True,
                showmeans=False, showfliers=False,
                medianprops={"color": "white", "linewidth": 0.5},
                boxprops={"facecolor": "C0", "edgecolor": "white",
                          "linewidth": 0.5},
                whiskerprops={"color": "C0", "linewidth": 1.5},
                capprops={"color": "C0", "linewidth": 1.5})

BpE = ax.boxplot(E, positions=[1,3,5]) # mostly default options for boxplot 

ax.set(xlim=(0, 8), xticks=np.arange(1, 8),
       ylim=(0, 8), yticks=np.arange(1, 8))

plt.show()
```

The result is one figure, with one axes, and two plots in that axes:

[image]

Here's the MVCE approach I took to your sample:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# make data:
np.random.seed(10)

D = np.random.normal((3, 5, 4), (1.25, 1.00, 1.25), (100, 3))
E = np.random.normal((2, 1, 5), (1.33, 1.00, 1.50), (100, 3))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
bplot2 = plt.boxplot(D)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
bplotm2 = plt.boxplot(E)

plt.show()
```

and its result, which is one figure, and two axes, with a boxplot in each axes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code to generate a tuple containing the figure and the axes and then assign the axes to your boxplots.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axes[0].boxplot(dff['totlngth'], vert = 1, patch_artist = True)
axes[1].boxplot(dfm['totlngth'], vert = None, patch_artist = True)
plt.show()
```